# VBscript C# function call and assignment of returned value

Tags: c#, vbscript, com

I have created a COM dll written in C#. It is registered successfully and I am trying to access it in VB script. I am able to create the object of the COM and am able to execute first method call.

When I try to execute the second method call (msg = app.getSubDomainConn( domain)), with the object returned by first method call, I get following error. I have posted both VBscript and C# code.

Could someone please help?

> Error: Invalid procedure call or argument: 'getValidConnectionMsg' 
> Code: 800A0005 
> Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

```
dim app 
Set app  = CreateObject("myCOM.myObject.")

app.uri=<URI>
app.username=<User>
app.password=<pwd>

Dim domain
Set domain = app.getDomain()
domain.ok = true;

wscript.echo domain.name

dim msg 
msg = app.getSubDomainConn(domain)
```

Here is C# code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace myCOM
{

    
    public class myObject
    {
        public String uri = "";
        public String username = "";
        public String password = "";

        public IDomain getDomain()
        {
            String msg = "";
             IDomain domain = null;
            try
            {

               
                // Get domain Connection
                IConnection conn = Factory.Connection.GetConnection(uri);
                UserCredentials creds = new UsernameCredentials(username, password);

                // Get domain.
                domain = Factory.Domain.Get(conn);
                

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
            }
            return domain;
        }



        public String getValidConnectionMsg(IDomain domain)
        {
            String isDomainAvailable = "Not Available";
            if (domain != null)
            {
                isDomainAvailable = domain.Name; 

            }

            return isDomainAvailable;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You [have been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70719190/object-passing-from-vbscript-to-c-sharp-com-dll#comment125019808_70719190) under the [previous incarnation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70719190/11683) of this question: "Is `getValidConnectionMsg` in your code somewhere?"

Comment: Yes getValidConnectionMsg is part of my C# code. I have given that code in my post.

Comment: The error is coming from VBScript. You are not calling `getValidConnectionMsg` from VBScript, so you cannot be getting that error. Instead you are calling `getSubDomainConn` from VBScript, which is not even present as a method in `myObject`. Which is why you were asked, Is getValidConnectionMsg in your code somewhere.

Comment: Why did you delete the previous question instead of just [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70719190/edit)? Deleting a question means any comments are lost.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that VB script variant datatype only considers object. I had to make a change in C# code. Instead of accepting it as a IDomain object, It should have been an Object type argument.
Instead of below

```
 public String getValidConnectionMsg(IDomain domain)
```

Modified code is

```
public String getValidConnectionMsg(Object d)
{
IDomain domain = (IDomain)d;
.
.
.
```

Comment: Explained here - [calling .NET COM object from VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4885360)